# Make a hemisphere with creases

Tags: modeling

I need to model the white hemisphere on top of the telescope tower of this observatory. As you can see, the hemisphere is not smooth, but it has some regular reliefs (I think they are called creases, but I am not sure). I have tried to use insets, blevels and creases, but I cannot get the desired results. Moreover, I didn't find anything in Google, but I am not sure how these reliefs are called, so probably I didn't search properly.

How would you proceed to create the reliefs of this hemisphere? (I have already made the hemisphere, it is just these regular edges in relief that I don't know how to model).

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select all base edge rings with *Select > Select Loops > Edge Rings* then deselect a desired ratio with the *Select > Checker Deselect* operator (may require an *Offset* value of $2$ for an even distribution).

Select all linked loops with *Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops* to extend the full corresponding loops.

Bevel the selected edges with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, then extrude them using the *Extrude Along Normals* option.

[image: Grooved Hemi]